# Modifying A record in bind server with DNSSEC

Tags: linux, debian, bind

System: Debian 10,

Bind: BIND 9.11.5-P4-5.1-Debian

named.conf.local:

```
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "/zones/db.example.com";
    inline-signing yes;
    auto-dnssec maintain;
    serial-update-method increment;
    key-directory "/etc/bind/keys";
};
```

DNSSEC (configured with official Debian [doc](https://wiki.debian.org/DNSSEC%20Howto%20for%20BIND%209.9+)) works fine. But update A record (modifying name and serial 2020051401 to 2020051501):
from:

```
testnode-100    IN  A   10.10.10.254
```

to:

```
testnode-010    IN  A   10.10.10.254
```

in db.example.com and restarting (rndc reload, service bind9 restart) doesn't change updated record in signed zone (a new serial number appears). 
dig query works on old record name only (testnode-100.example.com).

rndc zonestatus example.com:

```
name: example.com
type: master
files: /zones/db.example.com
serial: 2020051501
signed serial: 2020051501
nodes: 14
last loaded: Thu, 14 May 2020 11:32:07 GMT
secure: yes
inline signing: yes
key maintenance: automatic
next key event: Fri, 15 May 2020 08:22:32 GMT
next resign node: imap.example.com/A
next resign time: Wed, 20 May 2020 00:11:28 GMT
dynamic: no
reconfigurable via modzone: no
```

If I create new A record it can be queried (for example test.example.com), after delete it from db.example.com and restart bind I can still query this record.